# As we have the labeler functionality in d3 v3, is there any way to automatically place labels without overlapping in d3 v5?

Tags: angular, d3.js, bubble-chart

I need to place the labels for the scattered bubble chart without overlapping with other labels using angular 6. I saw the labeler function in d3 version 3. But I need a similar solution in d3 version5.
The labeler function or the plugin is not working in d3 version 5. The force based placement was not suiting because in my usecase I need to place the bubbles in a fixed position based on the data. Once the bubbles are placed, I need to place the labels without overlapping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have some code to share? I found this example, http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729 which may solve your need, but also looks quite old. I have a similar requirement, so would be interested to hear how you solve this

Comment: Here is a gist that shows it is possible to set up text labels to repel each other. https://gist.run/?id=641758fdb45992c381e33aefe99f437a I suppose it could be possible to set up the text labels to be attracted to their own bubbles, and repelled by other labels, just not sure how to do that yet (working on it)